# List all build errors at the end of Gradle log

Tags: java, gradle, junit, junit5

I have about 550 tests in my project and it is usually time consuming to locate these in a very lengthy debug log.

A typical error message from a test is like

```
 build  08-Oct-2018 15:17:18    com....IntegrationTest > testGetFilteringByMetadata FAILED
 build  08-Oct-2018 15:17:18        java.lang.AssertionError at IntegrationTest.java:148
```

Is it possible to collect failed test outpit somehow and  produce a summary of the failed tests at the end of the build scenario? At least, what test failed and on which line, and ideally full log output for each of failed tests.

I use JUnit and gradle.

Comment: did you check the content of the tests report generated by Gradle ? (in 
 `build/reports/tests/test/index.html` )

Comment: I have only access to the console log through my CI environment. In IDE, I have better ways to check what's happened in the test.

Comment: Considered using https://guides.gradle.org/creating-build-scans ?

Answer (score 2):

You can turn on logging for failed events as follows:

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()

    testLogging {
        events "failed" // "passed", "skipped", "standardOut", "standardError"
    }
}
```